# Stop Criteria JPA Like query converting NVARCHAR field to Varchar(255)

Tags: jpa, criteria, varchar, nvarchar

I am using JPA Criteria to run a like query on a NVARCHAR column. The column(events) can hold maximum(2000) characters. Now this is the query :

```
if (Objects.nonNull(eventStatus)) {
        String eStat = "\"event_status\"";
        String val ="\""+eventStatus+"\"";
    predicates.add(cb.like(item.get("events").as(String.class), "%"+eStat+"%"+" "+val+"%"));
    }
```

Now this is not generating expected result and when I saw query log I saw this :

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(itemadditi0_.item_additional_info_id) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        Allocation.item_additional_info itemadditi0_ 
    where
        itemadditi0_.tenant_id=? 
        and (
            cast(itemadditi0_.events as varchar(255)) like ?
        )
```

So I guess I am not getting the result because of this line : **`cast(itemadditi0_.events as varchar(255)) like ?`**

In SSMS this query working just fine:

```
(select item_nbr,item_status,events from Allocation.item_additional_info  where events like '%"event_status"%"Past"%');
```

In Model we are saving events as follow

```
@Column(name="events",columnDefinition="nvarchar")
    @Convert(converter = EventConverterJson.class)
    private List<EventInfo> events;
```

So can you please help me on how resolve issue like in this scenario ? Or how to stop JPA Criteria from that casting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out from the official doc that its a limitation of 'Like' predicate to consider first 255 characters. Anything larger than that will be ignored.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/like-predicate-limitations?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1):

Why are you casting the object to `String`?

This should work just fine:

```java
// Example: '%event_status% Past%'
final String likePattern =  "%"+eStat+"%"+val+" "+"%";
predicates.add(cb.like(item.get("events"), likePattern));
```

Assuming the `item` is of type `Root<...>`.

Also, the pattern you are using for the like predicate is different than the one you are showing as working (it contains an empty space and won't contain `"`). If you want to generate that exact pattern, you can do it with:

```java
// Example: '%"event_status"%"Past"%'
final String likePattern =  "%\"" + eStat + "\"%\"" + val+ "\"%";
```

Comment: Yes item is root..let me try this...Thank you so much for reply :)

Comment: If I remove string.class I am not getting any result.......Any alternative ?

Comment: The query is wrong. Make sure that the string in the second parameter of the like predicate is correct. I don't know what it should be because the one you use in the java example is different than the one you say it's working. You should also enable the SQL logs so that you can make sure that's the actual query is correct

Comment: In SQL log that explicit typecasting is not happening that I checked. However in the Model class we are saving events as object I have updated my question as well.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. It doesn't make any difference. Add in the question the exact SQL query you want to run and I can tell you how to generate it with criteria.

Comment: I have alredy mentioned in the question the query I want to execute (select item_nbr,item_status,events from Allocation.item_additional_info  where events like '%"event_status"%"Past"%'); where "Past" including the quotes is dynamic it can be "Past" , "Present", "Upcoming". I am wrapping the eventStatus with double quotes and keeping in variable val.

Comment: There is an additional empty space in the string you mention in the question. It also doesn't include the `"`. I will update the answer.

Comment: Now you should have all the information to write the right query. Good luck

Comment: that space is handled by % so I dont think so anything wrong in the matching part